# mvn release:prepare going into unending cycle

Tags: maven

I ran

> mvn release:prepare for a project and it is a multi-module build.

I entered yes for the following question :

```
There are still some remaining snapshot dependencies.: Do you want to
resolve them now? (yes/no) no: : yes
Dependency type to resolve,: specify the selection number ( 0:All 1:Project Dependencies 2:Plugins 3:Reports 4:Extensions ): (0/1/2/3) 1: :0
Resolve All Snapshots.: 'com.test:core-api' set to release? (yes/no) yes: : yes
What is the next development version? (0.0.6-SNAPSHOT) 0.0.6-SNAPSHOT: : 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

and it keeps on asking me the following in an unending cycle.

> What is the next development version?

I have to Ctrl+C to exit the loop.

Comment: Is it a mulit-module build?  If so, it will ask that question once for each submodule unless autoVersionSubModules is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue when I refactored the `groupId` in my multi-module build.

The cause is exactly what the error message says, but it can be elusive to spot the snapshots dependency.

In my case, the toplevel `groupId` and the `groupId`s in the `<parent>` stanzas in the submodules were all correct, but also some modules in the tree have cross dependencies to other modules, and as such are included in the `<dependencies>` or `<dependencyManagement>` stanzas.

These dependencies are tied to the project version by, well,`${project.version}`, so they're easy to miss in a text search for 'SNAPSHOT'. Since I forgot to refactor the `groupId`s in these dependencies, maven sees it as a 'foreign' snapshot dependency, outside of the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

From past experience it's not an un-ending cycle, but a HUGE amount of snapshots dependencies need to be confirmed (hence you get the impression it's an infinite loop). This typically happen in a maven aggregation (multi module) project.

If you know you always accept the DEFAULT answer, you can try running it in batch mode

```
mvn --batch-mode release:prepare
```

The default behavior of release plugin is to ask confirmation everytime it detects a snapshot dependencies. If you follow maven common practice, release your snapshot dependencies first and update reference to the dependencies before releasing your project.

http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html has a good information on performing non-interactive release

Comment: :I ran the above command and it came up with this : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project test-api: Can't release project due to non released dendencies :

Comment: As I said, that happens because you have snapshot dependencies on your project. If you follow maven common practice, you should release the dependencies first, update references to it, then release your code

Comment: @gerrytan Agreed you should release dependencies first.  But I don't think that is the cause here. The repeated question is "next development version?".  I suspect its a multi-module build with loads of submodules.

Comment: @SanikaJoshi check maven release:prepare manual: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html. There are many options you could try such as `updateDependencies`, `developmentVersion` etc, see if using those helps your problem. Also note the version that options have been available since. Some of them are newly introduced